# Find a positive integer $x$ less than $105$ satisfying the following simultaneous congruence equations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

> $$x=2 mod 3$$
>   $$x=3 mod 5$$
>   $$x=4 mod 7$$

I have only learnt modulo for 2 weeks so far... really basic theorems.

> My attempt using definitions of modulo

From Equation 1, $3a=x-2 \rightarrow 15a=5x-10$

From Equation 2, $5b=x-3 \rightarrow 15b=3x-9$

Adding them together, $15(a+b)=8x-19$ which implies, $8x=19mod15$ or $8x=4mod15$

and hence i am stuck....

please help, i can't seem to understand this at all.

Comment: The Chinese remainder theorem is useful here .. although I'm not sure if you are allowed to use it for your homework.

Comment: No sorry I haven't learnt that yet

Comment: This only uses basic algebra and modular arithmetic (maybe you could adapt it to your problem): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Finding_the_solution_with_basic_algebra_and_modular_arithmetic

Comment: thank you for your help tyler, i'll try to understand that meanwhile! seems useful

Comment: Use  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $x=3a+2=5b+3=7c+4$. From the second equality, you get that $3a+2=5b+3\Rightarrow 3a=5b+1$. If $b=3d$ or $b=3d+2$, you reach a contradiction, so $$b=3d+1\Rightarrow x=5b+3=5(3d+1)+3=15d+8.$$ From the last equation, $15d+8=7c+4\Rightarrow 15d+4=7c$. By contradiction you can check that $d=7e+3$, so $$x=15d+8=15(7e+3)+8=105e+53.$$ So, the number you ask for is $53$.

Answer (score 0):

$3a+2=5b+3\iff 3a=5b+1$

$\iff3(a-2)=5(b-1)$ (Subtracting either sides by $6$)

$\displaystyle\implies \frac{5(b-1)}3=a-2\text{ which is an integer}$

$\implies 3$ divides $5(b-1)\implies 3$ divides $(b-1)$ as $(5,3)=1$

$\implies b-1=3d\iff b=3d+1$ where $d$ is some integer

Again we have  $7c+4=5b+3=5(3d+1)+3\iff 7c+4=15d+8$

$\iff 7c=15d+4\iff 7(c-7)=15(d-3)$(Subtracting either sides by $49$)

$\displaystyle\implies \frac{7(c-7)}{15}=d-3$ which is an integer

$\implies 15$ divides $7(c-7)\implies 15$ divides $c-7$

$\implies c-7=15e$ where $e$ is any integer

$\implies x=7c+4=7(15e+7)+4=105e+53$